# Updated visual studio 2019 to visual studio 2022 and now xamarin android app crashes on startup

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

I updated my visual studio 2019 in order to build android apps with version >=12 as play store requires.

I’m using xamarin.android to develop my app, not xamarin.forms.

When I try to build the app and deploy on a physical device (Android version 11.0), as soon as the initial screen is displayed it crashes.

No exception/error is displayed in visual studio and when I try to open the app directly on the my device, it works fine.

I reinstalled all the nuget packages as some people suggested, enabled/disabled fast deployment, deleted obj/bin directories, nothing really worked yet…

Building my app with vs19 was working fine.

Anybody can help me with that?

I reinstalled all the nuget packages as some people suggested, enabled/disabled fast deployment, deleted obj/bin directories, nothing really worked yet…

Comment: 1) Close VS. Move "packages" folder and hidden ".vs" folder out of solution. Now delete all .bin and .obj folders (I know you already did, but making sure we simultaneous remove all sources of incompatibilities). 2) If still have problems, make a new xamarin.android project in a new folder. Look in its .csproj - what settings are different from yours? 3) Make a new initial screen that is blank. Doesn't run any code in constructor, except the default. Comment out any other special code you run during app startup. Still crash?

Comment: 4) Does new project in (2) crash at initial screen? If not, start adding your code to it, see if you can cause the crash.

Comment: Right...

1) didn't work, still crashing

2 and 3) creating a new project, it worked. I'm able to debug and run the "hello world" application. I tried using it's .csproj inside my application's .csproj, but I got this error:

Comment: XA0134: O aplicativo não tem o atributo 'android:debuggable' definido no AndroidManifest.xml. Isso é necessário para que a Implantação Rápida funcione. Isso é normalmente habilitado por padrão pelo 
 sistema de compilação Xamarin.Android para compilações de Depuração.Verifique se você não tem esse atributo
definido no elemento 'application' em seu 'AndroidManifest.xml'.Se você tiver uma classe que deriva de 'Android.App.Application' e estiver usando o '[Application]', certifique-se de que a propriedade 'Debuggable' não esteja definida,pois ela substituirá o valor das compilações de depuração

Comment: the problem with the 4th item you suggested is that my application requires a lot of code and packages, inserting this gradually is gonna take a longe time and I'm acually out of time... this new version is killing me.

is there any other suggestion besides that one?

Comment: Search for discussion of using jdk 11 with VS 2019. I'm fairly sure there is a way to make that work "well enough" (correct output, but perhaps some limitations). You'll hit the bug where it keeps going back to jdk 8. There's an answer, maybe in microsoft forums, that says to edit system environment variables to remove jdk 8 path. Plan to eventually move to VS 2022.

Answer (score 0):

How I solve this problem

STEP 1: first of all, uninstalled VS 2022. Not gonna need it so soon, I hope...

STEP 2: let's get back to VS 2019 which was working fine and follow this tutorial right here

https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/jdk-11-warning

this tutorial teachs us how to install JDK 11 manually and attach it to VS 2019 and to our project. it's great!

STEP 3: disable fast deployment (some tutorials from VS 2022 recommended to enable it, but didn't work)

STEP 4: add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ... xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ... >
  <application ... >

  <activity ... />
        <provider android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup" tools:node="merge">
                                     <meta-data android:name="androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleInitializer" android:value="androidx.startup" />
        </provider>
    </application> 
    
</manifest>
```

STEP 5: clean solution and compile

this is step-by-step how I solved this problem. Hope it helps you guys as well